# Input coordinate matrix from external file into 2 arrays

Tags: c++, arrays

I want to make 2 array `x[i]` and `y[i]` from external coordinate file but it just read only `y[i]` how can I read `x[i]`?

```
int main(){

ifstream fin;

int y[100];

int x[100];

int i=0,j=0;

int b;

fin.open("DataPoint.txt");

fin>>b;

if (fin.eof()){

       cout<<"File kosong"<< endl;

    }

else{

        do{
        fin>>y[i];cout<<y[i]<<endl;
        i++;
    }
    while(fin>>b);
}

fin.close();

return 0;

}
```

Comment: You could do it the exact same way that you are doing `y`

Comment: already tried but it cant for x i dont know why

Comment: You tried `in>>x[i];cout<<x[i]<<endl;`? What happened?

Comment: its show the y coordinate

Comment: and the x is 204879

Comment: the x is wrong it must be 1 and 3 but its show 204879

Comment: What is `while(fin>>b)` doing? This might be discarding your input

Comment: its looping do while for enter data into array

Comment: But what is the `b` for?

Comment: im define b as int data from external file so while( fin>>b) is conditional looping while there external file still have int data

Answer (score 0):

done thank you idan, this is my answer

int main() {

int j=0;

float x[100];

float y[100];

```
vector<int> numbers;

ifstream in("DataPoint.txt");

int number;
    while (in >> number) {
    numbers.push_back(number);
}
in.close();

for (int i=0; i<numbers.size(); i=i+2) {
    x[j]=numbers[i];j++;
}j=0;
for (int i=1; i<numbers.size(); i=i+2) {
    y[j]=numbers[i];j++;
}
```

refrence : http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/17845/